# How to change character code in Type1 font?

Tags: plain-tex

I needed to make spaces at the beginning of line copyable in pdf, and came up with the following trick.

In lm-rmtt.enc I change `/tilde` to `/nbspace` and then use this code:

```
\font\myfont=rm-lmtt10
\def\myspace{{\myfont\char`~}}
{\obeyspaces\global\let =\myspace}
```

This way, when when I say `\obeyspaces`, I get copyable spaces at the beginnig of line in pdf:

```
\font\tentt=cmtt10
\tentt
\obeyspaces
         hello
```

This works beautifully, but I wanted to ask if this way is "legal".
What becomes with the metrics if pdftex is used directly, and if dvipdfmx is used? I know they take metrics from Type1 fonts, without paying attention to tfm files. What metrics are used in this case?

Comment: Neither take metrics directly from type1 fonts. They both rely on the `.tfm` files. The only type1 font files they use are the `.pfb` (or `.pfa` files which do not contain any metrics. The metrics are contained in the `.afm` (or `.pfm` files but neither TeX nor pdfTeX uses those. When you create font support files, you use those files to create the `.tfm`files, along with other information. (Or, for pdfTeX, you can also create them from `.ttf` files for use with truetype fonts.)

Comment: @cfr: I don't understand .enc, .map and .pfb files. I just stumbled to this trick by occasion. Why does it work? In this case if .enc file is changed what metrics in taken for `/nbspace`? This character is not in .tfm at all.

Comment: `\newdimen\tempadimen
\advance\tempadimen by 10pt` ??

Comment: @cfr: what do you mean?

Comment: In your example, the change is global. Doesn't that do horrible things? If you do something like the above afterwards, you get errors. Could you clarify in what sense this works? I don't see any difference in the PDF. What is supposed to happen when I copy the line? I just get 'hello' as I would anyway.

Comment: @cfr: copy text from 'o' to beginning of line and insert into a text editor - it must appear with leading spaces, like ``\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ hello``, instead of `hello`, as it would by default. Sorry, I do not know how to format spaces properly so that they will not disappear

Comment: @cfr: as for global change, I specifically use a font which is not used otherwise. To be more clean, it is possible to create e.g. mytt10 and change encoding of that and use it in `\myfont`

Comment: So you are typing `\ \ \ ` and not `   ` in your source `.tex` document?

Comment: Even if I put that in the source, copying the line back to a text editor, I still get the first character as `h`. However, this is probably dependent on the PDF viewer. I think they likely deal differently with spaces.

Comment: @cfr: the example from the question should taken literally in the source `.tex` document. the backslashes are for the forum markup

Comment: Neither makes any difference to what gets copied back. As I say, I suspect this depends on your viewer. Obviously it works in yours and not in mine.

Comment: @cfr: I read on forums that non-breakable-space (U+00A0) is copied in all viewers correctly. Anyway, in `atril` viewer it works correctly.

Comment: It doesn't work in Okular. (So likely not other poppler-based viewers.) I doubt you are actually getting that character....

Comment: @cfr: my test.pdf is at http://expirebox.com/download/e0c3d1d21ae16d7eb2726a6b49a21ef9.html - please check if it works with your viewer. from my viewer the spaces are copied as U+0020, which is the needed behavior

Comment: @cfr: I checked it with okular - indeed the leading spaces are not copied, but in atril they are

Comment: It clearly depends on the PDF viewer. PDFKit based ones (on Mac OS X) don't copy spaces. Adobe Reader does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I tried compiling your example with `\pdfcompresslevel=0` and I got

```
BT
/F51 9.9626 Tf 91.925 759.927 Td [(~~~~~~~~~)]TJ/F30 9.9626 Tf 47.074 0 Td [(hello)]TJ/F1 9.9626 Tf 164.51 -654.747 Td [(1)]TJ
ET
```

As you see, the PDF file contains the repeated tilde, but the font resource has the modified encoding and so this tilde will appear as something else to the PDF viewer.

I did something else, then: I changed also `/i` into `/nbspace` and modified your example file into

```
\pdfcompresslevel=0
\pdfmapline{=rm-lmtt10 LMMono10-Regular " enclmrmtt ReEncodeFont " <lm-rmtt-mod.enc <lmtt10.pfb}

\font\myfont=rm-lmtt10
\def\myspace{{\myfont\char`~}}
{\obeyspaces\global\def {\myspace}}

\font\tentt=cmtt10
\tentt
\obeyspaces
         hello

\def\myspace{{\myfont\char`i}}%
         hello

\bye
```

(note that `lm-rmtt-mod.enc` is the modified `.enc` file, because I didn't want to tamper with default files). Here's what I get in the PDF file

```
BT
/F51 9.9626 Tf 91.925 759.927 Td [(~~~~~~~~~)]TJ/F30 9.9626 Tf 47.074 0 Td [(hello)]TJ/F51 9.9626 Tf -47.074 -11.955 Td [(iiiiiiiii)]TJ/F30 9.9626 Tf 47.074 0 Td [(hello)]TJ/F1 9.9626 Tf 164.51 -642.792 Td [(1)]TJ
ET
```

Here's what I see when I select all the text in Adobe Reader

[image]

which shows all spaces are “seen”.

If I do the same “select all” operation on Skim (an Apple PDFKit based previewer) I see instead

[image]

No spaces are copied. Therefore, the possibility of copying the spaces depends on the previewer.

Note however that, if I perform “copy” from Adobe Reader on the top line and then paste in an editor window, I get

[image]

What's “seen” are spaces, but the underlying text still has tildes.

Comment: Yes. Okular (and so probably Evince and other poppler-based viewers) behaves as Skim.

Answer (score 4):

You could also try `\pdffakespace` and `\pdfinterwordspaceon`. But while in the following example the "f"'s copy fine from the pdf, spaces are sometimes missing, or there is only one instead of many, 00A0 is copied as 0020 -- I don't think that TeX is removing them, it also happens with boxes between the spaces. So imho the pdf viewer is trying to be to intelligent.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\pdfglyphtounicode{space}{0066} %f to see it better
{\obeyspaces\gdef {~\pdffakespace}}

hello\pdffakespace hello

\obeyspaces 
x       hello

        g
\end{document}
```

This copies then as

```
hellofhello
x f f f f f f fhello
f f f f f f f fg
```