# Code environment that supports copy-paste

Tags: listings, code, copy-paste

Is there a LaTeX package that can generate code in PDF file and allow users to copy-paste the generated code?

I have tried the `lstlisting` environment. This is my test code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=fixed}
%%\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=flexible}
%%\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=fullflexible}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
print("helloworld")
print("hello world")
print("hello  world")
print("hello   world")
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

When `columns` is set to `fixed`, the package inserts extra spaces into the PDF file. When set to `flexible` or `fullflexible`, multiple spaces are reduced into one. The latter is obviously unacceptable. So I think the only usable option is `fixed`. But the extra spaces are very annoying and I don't know how to deal with them.

Comment: There is no reliable way. If you want to pass source code, embed it. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472112/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer What do you mean by "embed"?

Comment: see the attachfile2 or the embedfile package.