# Minted copyable spaces

Tags: pdf, verbatim, minted

I looked at a lot of answers regarding this topic, but they all seemed to be pretty old. I also looked into the documentation of the minted package, which did not give me a solution either. I want a minted output where you can copy the blank spaces used for intentions. Can someone help me?

Short example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
    \begin{minted}{python}
def foo():
    x = 42
    print("please let me copy the spacing")
    return
    \end{minted}
\end{document}
```

When I try to copy the code, I get the following:

[image]

Is there an update or a new solution to that problem?

Comment: no. Nothing has changed compared to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472112/2388. It is an open problem of pdf.